# Newtonsoft.Json JsonConvert To Datatable

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a code like this,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string data = "{\"ProductId\":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77],\"ProductName\":[\"Chai\",\"Chang\",\"Aniseed Syrup\",\"Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning\",\"Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix\",\"Grandma's Boysenberry Spread\",\"Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears\",\"Northwoods Cranberry Sauce\",\"Mishi Kobe Niku\",\"Ikura\",\"Queso Cabrales\",\"Queso Manchego La Pastora\",\"Konbu\",\"Tofu\",\"Genen Shouyu\",\"Pavlova\",\"Alice Mutton\",\"Carnarvon Tigers\",\"Teatime Chocolate Biscuits\",\"Sir Rodney's Marmalade\",\"Sir Rodney's Scones\",\"Gustaf's KnÃ¤ckebrÃ¶d\",\"TunnbrÃ¶d\",\"GuaranÃ¡ FantÃ¡stica\",\"NuNuCa NuÃŸ-Nougat-Creme\",\"GumbÃ¤r GummibÃ¤rchen\",\"Schoggi Schokolade\",\"RÃ¶ssle Sauerkraut\",\"ThÃ¼ringer Rostbratwurst\",\"Nord-Ost Matjeshering\",\"Gorgonzola Telino\",\"Mascarpone Fabioli\",\"Geitost\",\"Sasquatch Ale\",\"Steeleye Stout\",\"Inlagd Sill\",\"Gravad lax\",\"CÃ´te de Blaye\",\"Chartreuse verte\",\"Boston Crab Meat\",\"Jack's New England Clam Chowder\",\"Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee\",\"Ipoh Coffee\",\"Gula Malacca\",\"Rogede sild\",\"Spegesild\",\"Zaanse koeken\",\"Chocolade\",\"Maxilaku\",\"Valkoinen suklaa\",\"Manjimup Dried Apples\",\"Filo Mix\",\"Perth Pasties\",\"TourtiÃ¨re\",\"PÃ¢tÃ© chinois\",\"Gnocchi di nonna Alice\",\"Ravioli Angelo\",\"Escargots de Bourgogne\",\"Raclette Courdavault\",\"Camembert Pierrot\",\"Sirop d'Ã©rable\",\"Tarte au sucre\",\"Vegie-spread\",\"Wimmers gute SemmelknÃ¶del\",\"Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce\",\"Louisiana Hot Spiced Okra\",\"Laughing Lumberjack Lager\",\"Scottish Longbreads\",\"Gudbrandsdalsost\",\"Outback Lager\",\"Flotemysost\",\"Mozzarella di Giovanni\",\"RÃ¶d Kaviar\",\"Longlife Tofu\",\"RhÃ¶nbrÃ¤u Klosterbier\",\"LakkalikÃ¶Ã¶ri\",\"Original Frankfurter grÃ¼ne SoÃŸe\"]}";

dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(data);
```

If I run this data on online json editor as remove `\` char, it's showing. But in Visual Studio, there is an error,

```
Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

on last code place.

I want to, convert data to DataTable using Newtonsoft plugin. How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27831829/2457113).
The trick to have the json string as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` cannot be converted to `Datatabe`

When I try your code it gives me:

> Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing
>   object.

However when I do:

```
object obj  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
```

works fine.

You can also create your own class:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int[] productId { get; set; }
    public string[] ProductName { get; set; }
}

MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(data);
```

So for different types of data you have, you can create different classes:

```
    public class MyObject2{
    ...
    }

    public class MyObject3{
    ...
    }
    ...

Object obj = null;
try{
 obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(data); 
}catch{
      try{
      obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject2>(data);
      }catch{
           try{
             obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject3>(data);
           }catch{
             //Log error new type of data received
             throw new Exception();
           }
      }

}
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(MyObject)){
   ...
}else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(MyObject2)){
   ...
}
....
```

Comment: You write MyObject class. But income data, changable, not stable. In this situation what can i do?

Comment: Probably you have some different data formats, for  each of them create classes and do in `try catch` blocks

Comment: If you have a time, could you your answer, you say?

Comment: I did not understand what you ask

Comment: Sorry, could you figure code which you say, If you have a time. Because I'm working until 2 day, i couldn't solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your json must be an array of objects to be converted to a DataTable, it must start like this :

```
"[{\"ProductId\..........
```

end ends like this:

```
....,\"fieldName\":Value}]"
```